# Sending Mouse Input to Another Application Without Focus

Tags: input, io, mouse, sendmessage, postmessage

I'll try to describe my problem and question as clearly as possible,

I am attempting to create a program that would allow you to plug two keyboards and mice into a single computer and play two copies of the same game at the same time by splitting their inputs to the different application windows. I found no good tool for this online, so I'm making my own.

From all my research and testing it seems like SendMessage and PostMessage are my best bet. I've been intercepting WM_INPUT messages and sending them to the desired application and so far this has been working... to an extent.

I have two videos to help you understand the problem I'm experiencing:
The first simply shows my program working as I would expect when sending input to Chrome. As I scroll around and click on the InputMapper window you can see Chrome reacting to the superimposed cursor as if I were scrolling right over it.
[Video 1: Nice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHMDmxF3A-I)

The second video shows me doing the exact same thing with a game's client, and for some reason it does not quite work right. It just plain doesn't work with the dummy cursor, but it does respond to the *real* cursor, even though the window technically doesn't have focus (which tells me that the PostMessage is working, but it just refuses to acknowledge the clicks at the location of the dummy cursor instead of the real cursor). [Video 2: Not Quite](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EYqBsst979k)

So my question is simple: I am using the same code in both scenarios, but the two applications responded differently and it didn't quite work for the game client. Does anyone have any idea why I would be getting this behavior? 
It seems like the game is for whatever reason still registering clicks as being at the location of the real cursor and not the location of the L_PARAM that I send it.

To give an example of my code for handling mouse click events, here you go:

```
private void m_MouseButtonDown(object sender, InputDevice.MouseControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Mouse.deviceHandle != MouseHandle1)
            return;

        uint L_Param_Window = (uint)(cursorPosX + ((int)cursorPosY << 16));

        uint W_Param = 0;
        switch (e.Mouse.buttonMessage)
        {
            case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
                W_Param = (uint)MouseButtons.LEFT;
                break;
            case WM_MBUTTONDOWN:
                W_Param = (uint)MouseButtons.MIDDLE;
                break;
            case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
                W_Param = (uint)MouseButtons.RIGHT;
                break;
        }

        // Send Messages
        PostMessage(applicationHandle1, e.Mouse.buttonMessage, (IntPtr)W_Param, (IntPtr)L_Param_Window);
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Edit: fixed the video links because I noticed I'm a dummy

Edit 2: Updated because I've improved the program a bit and hopefully my problem is more clear
Also: I have a theory that *maybe* it is doing this because of how the cursor's image changes in the game client. So maybe there's some kind of underlying aspect of that that is breaking what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could send message keyboard or message mouse to a specific handle with Sendmessage by giving the handle, but the problem is to identify the origin of the message : what is the device who sends this message?? To distinguish between input devices, you  need to use Raw Input API.  Thas requires some skills....